# Integrate cordova based android mobile app with google analytics property 4

Tags: android, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, google-analytics-4

Steps to set up a new Analytics link

[Integration source](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9289234?hl=en#:%7E:text=If%20you%20already%20have%20one,name%20Default%20Account%20for%20Firebase.)

[image]

[image]

we followed above mentioned steps successfully for android app build using cordova but not able to reach 5th step.Am I missing something here? Suggest any other approach to track mobile app activity using google analytics4 property.

we used **cordova to build mobile android app.**

Above steps maybe for native mobile app only or in case of cordova  based build will need plugin to support integration of google analytics.Any leads appreciated .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Open your android folder which comes under platform folder.
In android studio and then you will find **'sync now'** button in android studio